# How to reduce Azure web app temp file usage

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a couple of small web apps hosted in Azure. I am using a shared app service, not VMs. Recently Azure has started showing warnings that I need to reduce my app's usage of temporary files on workers.

[image]

The [link from the message](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system) doesn't provide anything useful for resolving this.

After restarting the app, the problem has gone away. Seems that temporary apps were cleared by doing a restart.

I am not sure what generated 179GB of temporary files and how I can reduce this. What should I look for? I am not explicitly storing anything in temporary files in code, data is stored in the database, so not sure what to look for.

Answer (score 2):

The temp file usage is probably caused by one of your app that keeps creating temp files without cleaning them up. Restarting cleans up everything, but it's likely going to grow back over time if your app keeps doing the same thing.

There is no single solution to fix this. You'll need to figure out what causes this is your app logic, and change it to better clean up after itself.

Comment: David, where can I see what kind of files are being written to that "temp files" folder? How can I browse these files?